# Incorrect auto generated "Stack Overflow join" date in developer story

Tags: bug, developer-story

I used to have two accounts, one that I created in 2011, and one I created in 2014. Towards the end of last year, I had these two accounts merged.

Today, I created a developer story for the first time, and the auto generated "Stack Overflow join" date was showing 2014, which is the second account and not the first (2011).

After an account merge, shouldn't only the earliest join date have been kept?

I have since removed the "Stack Overflow join" date from the developer story because I couldn't change it.

The "Member for X years, Y months" shown on my profile is correct.

Comment: Please make your developer story public so we can see the issue.

Comment: This is such a heart warming story, two accounts on a journey of love and a dev story to go with it.